# Parallax Scrolling is Choppy in Safari only

Tags: safari, parallax

I currently am working with a web company who has coded most of my website.  They are about to hand the site off to me however there is an issue with the parallax scrolling in Safari; Works great in all other browsers.  Also, I have a widget on the left side of the page that is affected as well.  Very choppy when scrolling vertically.   Any suggestions and help is greatly appreciated.  Here is the link to the site:

http://zerochroma.nclud.me/product/vario-protect-iphone-4-4s

The issue seems to be in safari only.

Comment: New Site Link:  staging.zerochroma.com

Comment: I fixed the widget with -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
But my parallax scrolling is still jerky.  Could it be do to the fact that the background images are set to "cover"??

Comment: I found what is causing the issue.  background-attachment: fixed; in safari only.  However, I need a fixed bg for my parallax.  Any suggestions?